# C variadic function behavior differs from expected equivalent code in an Erlang driver

Tags: c, variadic-functions, erlang-driver

I replaced following code

```
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 9] = ERL_DRV_ATOM;
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 8] = drv->atom_error;
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 7] = ERL_DRV_INT;
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 6] = error_code;
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 5] = ERL_DRV_STRING;
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 4] = (ErlDrvTermData) error;
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 3] = strlen(error);
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 2] = ERL_DRV_TUPLE;
(*dataset_p)[*term_count_p - 1] = 3;
```

(where `dataset_p` has type `ErlDrvTermData**` and `term_count_p` is an `int*`) with

```
append_to_dataset(9, *dataset_p, *term_count_p,
  ERL_DRV_ATOM, drv->atom_error,
  ERL_DRV_INT, error_code,
  ERL_DRV_STRING, (ErlDrvTermData) error, strlen(error),
  ERL_DRV_TUPLE, 3);
```

where `append_to_dataset` is defined as

```
void append_to_dataset(int n, ErlDrvTermData* dataset, int term_count, ...) {
  int i;
  va_list new_terms;
  va_start(new_terms, term_count);

  for (i = -n; i < 0; i++) {
    dataset[term_count + i] = va_arg(new_terms, ErlDrvTermData);
  }
  va_end(new_terms);
}
```

[(diff to see that's the entire difference).](https://github.com/alexeyr/erlang-sqlite3/compare/alexeyr:ea9fa6093ad25e4546990d7459d8741ea035c6b9...64e7095b53a65c2cbd847ee518b87f339d86c890) It looks to me like behavior should be exactly identical, but while tests pass on the [original code](https://github.com/alexeyr/erlang-sqlite3/blob/ea9fa6093ad25e4546990d7459d8741ea035c6b9/c_src/sqlite3_drv.c), the [new version](https://github.com/alexeyr/erlang-sqlite3/blob/64e7095b53a65c2cbd847ee518b87f339d86c890/c_src/sqlite3_drv.c) fails with an error message:

```
HUGE size (47278999994405)
make: *** [test] Aborted
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You are possibly using negative indices if *term_count is less than 9. Or it could be that your for-loop is trying to index a pointer which is not an array, i.e. trying to index an individual value like `"ERL_DRV_ATOM"`

Comment: What is `ErlDrvTermData`? If it's wider than `int`, the `3` must be cast when passed to `append_to_dataset`.

Comment: Good point, @mafso, but it applies equally to both codes, so it doesn't explain why they behave differently.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: In the first code, there's an explicit conversion, in the second code, we have default argument promotions due to the vararg function. For example, with `typedef long ErlDrvTermData` a `3` (of type `int`) is passed to `append_to_dataset` and fetched as a `long`. The same may apply to all the arguments after the first two, actually.

Comment: I meant _implicit_ conversion, of course. Sorry, too late now...

Comment: @mafso, my bad.  In that case, I observe that the varargs function is called with one argument of type `size_t` and another of type `int`.  If the sizes of those types are not the same then it cannot be that they both match the size of `ErlDrvTermData`.

Comment: @mafso Thanks, this seems like a possible answer (`ErlDrvTermData` is `unsigned __int64` under Windows and `unsigned long` under Linux). I'll test it when I get an opportunity.

Comment: @mafso Yes, this was the problem. Please write an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the types of the expressions on the right hand side of the assignments in the first code snippet, the two code snippets may not be equivalent.

Variable arguments undergo default argument promotions but no other conversion (as opposed to calling a prototyped function, where arguments are converted if necessary if they’re assignment-compatible). For the second code to work they must be of type `ErlDrvTermData` which in turn must the same as its default-promoted type to fetch the corresponding arguments correctly via `va_arg`.

In particular, every argument but the first two (which aren’t variable arguments) need an explicit cast to be converted correctly:

```
append_to_dataset(9, *dataset_p, *term_count_p,
  (ErlDrvTermData)ERL_DRV_ATOM, (ErlDrvTermData)drv->atom_error,
  (ErlDrvTermData)ERL_DRV_INT, (ErlDrvTermData)error_code,
  (ErlDrvTermData)ERL_DRV_STRING,
  (ErlDrvTermData) error, (ErlDrvTermData)strlen(error),
  (ErlDrvTermData)ERL_DRV_TUPLE, 3);
```

assuming the conversions are value-preserving. If `ErlDrvTermData` is, for example, `typedef`ed to a `short`, it must be fetched as an `int`:

```
dataset[term_count + i] = va_arg(new_terms, int);
```